# this following code is working for removing the previous data from the modal

Tags: javascript

this following code is working for removing the previous data from the modal but my requirement is i have 2 hyperlinks in the data table 1st won is edit and 2nd won is delete when i click on delete link data is deleting then after i click on edit link then 404 error is occured(both links are concatinating) 
i tried this following code for removing the previous data from the modal

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
 var target = $(e.target);
 target.removeData('bs.modal')
 .find(".modal-content").html('');
        });
```

Comment: Please add a descriptive title and punctuation to your question.

Comment: Your context is vague for anyone to answer your question. Please provide the full html code in order for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: iam filing data table using ajax on that table i have 2 hyperlinks (Edit and Delete) if we click on those hyperlinks bootstrap model will be open and performs the Edit and delete functionalities my problem is after clicking on Edit link and update the data then click on delete link then 404 error is occurring ( http://192.168.7.120:9090/accounts/AdjustmentStock/accounts/DeleteAdjustmentSerialNumber/245245246)